# Class variable not saved

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm working on a simple python class but i have the strangest problem with assigning a value to a class variable

```
class browser(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.event_url = url

    def find(self):
        print(self.event_url)

browser = browser('this is a test string')
browser.find    #this prints an empty string...
```

With experiance on other languages i assume self.event_url now contains 'this is a test string'. I can confirm this by printing the value in **init**. This works fine. But when i want to access this value from a other function the variable is empty.

I hope someone can explain me what i'm not seeing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to **call** `find`, so `browser.find()`. If you write `browser.find` you only obtained a (partial) function.

Comment: `#this prints an empty string...` your observation is wrong. This line does not print at all. It simply references the `find` method. BTW, `event_url` is an instance-level variable (attribute to be precise), not class-level.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> browser.find    #this prints an empty string...
> ```

No it does not, **it prints nothing at all**. If you write `browser.find`, you obtain a reference to the `find` function (with the `self` already filled in). But you did **not call the function**. You should write:

```
browser.find()
#           ^^ function call
```

Furthermore note that - like [@JonClements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096271/class-variable-not-saved/44096302?noredirect=1#comment75213424_44096302) says - you should **name your class with an uppercase**, so `Browser`. Otherwise if you write `browser = browser()`, you can no longer construct new browsers.

Comment: Might want to note the OP should rename their class to `Browser` - they've clobbered their class definition with an instance here which is just going to cause more problems later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put browser.find().  You forgot the parentheses.